# How do if statements work?

Tags: python, if-statement

I am making a text based russian roulette game in Python, but I am not nearly finished, as one can see just by looking at my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print("The maximum number of bullets is 3")
bulletcounter = input("How many bullets do you want your gun to have?")
print(bulletcounter, "bullets")
paname = input("Enter Player 1's Name: ")
pbname = input("Enter Player 2's Name: ")
print(paname.capitalize(), "Vs.", pbname.capitalize())
if bulletcounter == 1:
    bulletcount = 0
    print(bulletcount)
    bulletaloc = random.randint(1, 6)
    while bulletaloc != bulletcount:
        bulletcount += 1
```

For some reason, even if someone enters `1` into `bulletcounter`, it doesn't trigger the `if` statement: `if bulletcounter == 1`. How do I make it trigger the `if` statement?

Comment: What particular behaviour leads you to believe that the `if` statement is not being executed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `raw_input` for your `paname` and `pbname` variables. Be sure to `import random` at the top of your file. It would also be better to use `int(raw_input("How many..."))` for `bulletcounter`, too, I think, than `input`, since this can be used to evaluate any arbitrary python code.

Also, it would be worth checking to see which version of Python you are using, when you invoke it using the `env` command. If, at the command line, you run:

```
/usr/bin/env python -V
```

and are getting "Python 2.x.y" instead of Python 3, and you are expecting to be using Python 3, consider changing that first line to call your Python 3 interpreter instead. The recommendations noted above assume you are using Python 2.

Comment: Doesn't that depend on the Python version? I thought `raw_input` was removed (and `input` changed to replace it, by not executing its contents) in Python 3?

Comment: @paxdiablo, okay, but the code starts with `env python`, which means we can't easily see what version of Python is being used. While we might assume the intention was for Python 3 given the style, what if the OP has two versions of Python installed in the environment, and Python 2 happens to be further up in the path? When making the changes I suggested, it works for Python 2.

Comment: imm, I wasn't saying your answer was _wrong,_ just that you seem to be making an assumption. It would be worth noting that in the answer.